# Linking to Resources from Template

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel

I am a beginner at Laravel, but am starting to use the blade template. I have a lot of css and js calls, and I'd like to use those resources. However, I would also like to use the same blade template in different folders in my views.

In my views, I have folders for init operations, and folders for other normal uses, so the path to the css and/or js files are always different.

How should I write my .blade.php template so that it will be able to access the css and js files when the view is in any directory within views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put all your assets in the `public` directory and import your CSS and JS files using Laravel HTML class static methods:

```
{{ HTML::style('style.css'); }}
{{ HTML::script('script.js'); }}
```

The path should always be relative to the public directory regardless of your current directory.